# ProgressDialog doesn't appear immediately

Tags: android, bitmap, handler, progressdialog, fragment

I have a fragment with some buttons in it, when a button is clicked it should show a ProgressDialog, load an array of bitmaps and show it in the fragment in a gallery, dismiss ProgressDialog.

But the ProgressDialog doesn't show immediately, it take something like 1 or 2 seconds and it just blink at the moment when my gallery is show.

Im doing this after click:

```
try{
    progress = ProgressDialog.show(activity, "", "Loading images", true);

    //load images
    //show gallery

}catch(){
    //...
}finally{
    handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
}
```

My Handler at onCreate:

```
handler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
         progress.dismiss();
    }
};
```

Im using Android 3.1

Logcat shows anything :(

```
03-09 13:17:32.310: D/DEBUG(5695): before show()
03-09 13:17:32.350: D/DEBUG(5695): after show()
```

Comment: post you full code? Are you used Thread or Async for this ?

Comment: @Samir: He said he creates `Handler` at `onCreate`, and show `ProgressDialog` after click. I see no problem about that code.

Comment: @rafael: Could you please filter the logs? For example: `import android.util.Log; ... Log.d("your-tag", "before show()"); progressDialog.show(); Log.d("your-tag", "after show()");`... And filter all logs made by your application only.

Comment: @rafael: Thanks a lot. But I could not help you, this is strange  :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are loading the images on the main UI thread - you should do this in a background process as it may cause your UI to become unresponsive (and cause your `ProgressDialog` to show up at the wrong time).

You should look into using an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to carry out loading of the images in the background.

Display the `ProgressDialog` in `AsyncTask.onPreExecute`, load images in `AsyncTask.doInBackground` and dismiss the dialog in `AsyncTask.onPostExecute`.

Comment: Thanks, the click event wasn't  being consumed until the images load , i moved the load code to inside AsyncTask and it worked

Answer (score 1):

Documentation does not tell much about [setIndeterminate(boolean)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html#setIndeterminate%28boolean%29), so I'm not sure. But I use this in my app, and it works:

```
ProgressDialog fDialog = new ProgressDialog(your-context);
fDialog.setMessage(your-message);
fDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
// fDialog.setCancelable(cancelable);
fDialog.show();
```

Could you try it?

Comment: Same result. I tried to put a Thread.sleep(5000); after load images and the ProgressDialog just started after this, almost at same time of show gallery =(